# Installing the Bouncy Castle Provider in jdk-15.0.2

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

I installed Bouncy Castle Provider for a Java old version configuring the Java Runtime following [this guide](https://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/22/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-jse-projects/). All worked fine. To use unrestricted policy files I installed an openJDK (15.0.2), but now the BC provider doesn't work anymore. Of course I tried to do again the installing procedure without any success. The jdk-15.0.2 do not comes with a jre since it is a new version, so that procedure do not work well anymore. I use the jre1.8.0_241 version and I already modified the *java.security* file to enable BC. Where do I wrong?

Comment: I do not have JDK 15 but the earlier JDKs do come with java.security file, too. Just find it in the JDK directory.

Comment: The 'lib/ext' directory no longer exists in Java 9 up; you must use a directory in the classpath instead. There is no longer a separate _directory_ named `jre` but the JRE itself is still there as a subset of the JDK. The `java.security` file is now in `JDK/conf/security` instead of `JDK/jre/lib/security`. There are no longer unlimited-policy files; all versions j9 up and 8u161 up have unlimited-policy built in.

Comment: do you really need bouncy castle with Java 15? most popular encryption algorithms have been supported already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with the `certificate` used to sign bouncy castle security provider jar.

The CA of this certificate is no longer embedded in versions of JVM greater than 261, so you have to update your bouncy castle version to a newer version that is already signed with Oracle certificates or manually install the certificate in trusted ca certificates of the JVM.

[sun microsystem certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6upHG.png)